# WordPress $wpdb->update set float to null?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to set a column to `NULL` using `$wpdb->update();`?

When I attempt to, WordPress attempts to typecast that column to a float, which converts `NULL` to `0`.

I've checked the core code and inside of `$wpdb->update()`, the `$format` parameter is only expecting %s, %f, and %d. I went so far as to set `$wpdb->field_types['myCol']` to `'NULL'`, but both only serve to break `$wpdb->update()`'s query (interestingly enough, it shifts the values for each column over after the `NULL`).

There is a related question here, but that answer only deals with `INSERT`, **not** `UPDATE`.

From a data integrity standpoint, `NULL` is very important for this column, so I have to be able to set it as such when necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596962/wordpress-database-insert-and-update-using-null-values

Comment: @Set Sail Media That's the question that references only `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you yourself note, the `$format` parameter is only expecting `%s`, `%f`, and `%d`. The whole thing will get passed through [`prepare`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/wp-db.php) which also doesn't take a `null` format specifier because it basically accepts the same format specifiers that are accepted by [`(v)(s)printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) but without the argument swapping. You can't pass `NULL` through `update`. You have the same choices as mentioned in [the post suggested as a possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596962/wordpress-database-insert-and-update-using-null-values), and in essence it is.

1. Just don't use the `update` function. Write your own SQL and use it with `$wpdb->query`. If you are dealing with your own tables that should be fine.
2. Create your own database class that *will* do what you want. It is a little know fact that you can replace WordPress' `$wpdb` with a [drop-in](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that modifies the wpdb from the latest version of wordpress, in order to allow inserting and updating null values into SQL tables using insert() and update():

```
/*
 * Fix wpdb to allow inserting/updating of null values into tables
 */
class wpdbfixed extends wpdb
{
    function insert($table, $data, $format = null) {
        $type = 'INSERT';
        if ( ! in_array( strtoupper( $type ), array( 'REPLACE', 'INSERT' ) ) )
            return false;
        $this->insert_id = 0;
        $formats = $format = (array) $format;
        $fields = array_keys( $data );
        $formatted_fields = array();
        foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
            if ( !empty( $format ) )
                $form = ( $form = array_shift( $formats ) ) ? $form : $format[0];
            elseif ( isset( $this->field_types[$field] ) )
                $form = $this->field_types[$field];
            else
                $form = '%s';

            //***edit begin here***
            if ($data[$field]===null) {
                unset($data[$field]); //Remove this element from array, so we don't try to insert its value into the %s/%d/%f parts during prepare().  Without this, array would become shifted.
                $formatted_fields[] = 'NULL';
            } else {
                $formatted_fields[] = $form; //Original line of code
            }
            //***edit ends here***
        }
        $sql = "{$type} INTO `$table` (`" . implode( '`,`', $fields ) . "`) VALUES (" . implode( ",", $formatted_fields ) . ")";
        return $this->query( $this->prepare( $sql, $data ) );
    }

    function update($table, $data, $where, $format = null, $where_format = null)
    {
        if ( ! is_array( $data ) || ! is_array( $where ) )
            return false;

        $formats = $format = (array) $format;
        $bits = $wheres = array();
        foreach ( (array) array_keys( $data ) as $field ) {
            if ( !empty( $format ) )
                $form = ( $form = array_shift( $formats ) ) ? $form : $format[0];
            elseif ( isset($this->field_types[$field]) )
                $form = $this->field_types[$field];
            else
                $form = '%s';

            //***edit begin here***
            if ($data[$field]===null)
            {
                unset($data[$field]); //Remove this element from array, so we don't try to insert its value into the %s/%d/%f parts during prepare().  Without this, array would become shifted.
                $bits[] = "`$field` = NULL";
            } else {
                $bits[] = "`$field` = {$form}"; //Original line of code
            }
            //***edit ends here***
        }

        $where_formats = $where_format = (array) $where_format;
        foreach ( (array) array_keys( $where ) as $field ) {
            if ( !empty( $where_format ) )
                $form = ( $form = array_shift( $where_formats ) ) ? $form : $where_format[0];
            elseif ( isset( $this->field_types[$field] ) )
                $form = $this->field_types[$field];
            else
                $form = '%s';
            $wheres[] = "`$field` = {$form}";
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE `$table` SET " . implode( ', ', $bits ) . ' WHERE ' . implode( ' AND ', $wheres );
        return $this->query( $this->prepare( $sql, array_merge( array_values( $data ), array_values( $where ) ) ) );
    }

}
global $wpdb_allow_null;
$wpdb_allow_null = new wpdbfixed(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
```

Insert this code into somewhere that always gets run, like your functions.php, and then use your new global $wpdb_allowed_null->insert() and ->update() as normal.

I preferred doing it this way vs. overriding the default $wpdb, in order to preserve the DB behavior that the rest of Wordpress and other plugins will expect.